# PHPDoc interface binding in PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have a class that is bound to interface in Laravel, so when I inject the interface I have access to the bound methods and properties.

I don't why, but PhpStorm detect the bound method but not the properties !

Is there anyway to till the IDE about the properties ?

e.g:

```
class cls{
    public $pro;

    public function foo()
    {

    }
}

interface clsInterface{
}
```

now binding it in AppServiceProvider:

```
$this->app->bind(clsInterface::class,cls::class);
```

after that, in any controller I inject the interface:

```
class P2PController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(clsInterface $interface)
    {
        //now when calling $interface-> , phpstorm detect foo function but doesn't detect $pro
        // if I type $interface->pro; phpstorm will raise warning "field pro not found"

    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a clear standalone working example. Your current code does not show anything useful.

Comment: @LazyOne ok, I think now it is clearer

Comment: Interfaces don't have properties in PHP

Comment: Exactly what Ross Wilson have said: you cannot access class property/variable via interface as PHP interfaces do not allow declaring them (in interface) so you will only see what interface declares (methods and constants). You can do something like this in PhpStorm (`/** @property $pro */
interface clsInterface{...}`) to declare property via PHPDoc, but that's not a correct way, rather a hack. Use a proper method (e.g. getter/setter to access such property).